# C# GUI and Async Client Socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sockets, asynchronous

I'm creating a library with a client socket and capture data (Async). I know that when an UI use this library is gonna need save thread treatment, So I'm wandering if there is a way to treat this problem in a library and free the UI for having to do the save thread treatment.

What I'm doing is creating an event when I receive data but this new event is running in a different thread than the UI so this will create the "Crossover threat problem" so I need to do save thread treatment in the UI. But then, all UI using my library have to do the same save thread treatment for all components?

..........................
This is the new aproach with Bradley Uffner and Ananke Ideas:

```
public class ClientControler
{   
    private ClientSocket Client { get; set; }
    private Form Main { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;
    public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> Received;

    protected virtual void ReceivedCall(string name, int number)
    {
        if (Received != null)
        {
            Received(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs(name, number));
        }
    }

    public ClientControler(Form main)
    {
        Main = main;
        Client = new ClientSocket("127.0.0.1", 8080);
        // (1) this is when the socket send the data
        Client.DataReceived += OnReceived;

        Client.Connect();

        // (4) DataReceived delegate has OnUpdated asigned and then call
        DataReceived = new EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs>(OnUpdated); 
    }

    // (2) the socket data is received here
    public void OnReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // (3) Main Form Invoke DataReceived delegate
        Main.Invoke(DataReceived, this, e);
    }

    // (5) OnUpdated is called in the same thread of the Main Form
    public void OnUpdated(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReceivedCall(e.name, e.number);// (6) Event launch
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ClientControler Control { get; set; }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Control = new ClientControler(this);//Connecting the socket
        Control.Received += OnReceived;//Waiting for the Event
    }

    public void OnReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        This is where the problem was before, 
        normaly I had to code save thread here but now is just working.
        */
        label1.Text = e.name;
        label2.Text = e.number.ToString();
        Log("Viewer", "Client", "Received", e.name);//this method just add 
        //a log to a listbox where you have to code save thread too,
        //without this solution
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the right way but is working Thanks to you. Thank you very much. Any sugestion just write please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consuming client application can invoke on the Control or Form to update it, so you can just raise your 'DataReceived' event on any thread that you like.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm analyzing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution this in the past has been for the application using the library to send a reference to the form in to the the library.  The library saves this references and automatically wraps all events in a call to .BeginInvoke on that form instance.  That way the application code never has to worry about making sure the calls from the library are on the correct thread.

Comment: Can you give me an example of code for better understanding?